# Changing the the language of strings in Zurb Foundation 4

Tags: zurb-foundation

I want to use the responsive dropdown thats built in to Foundation and it works great, but when it's displayed on a smaller device is shows a "back" button and since I'm building a site for a german audience I'll need to change that string.

So it would be nice if someone could tell me where I can find it, since it isn't in the javascript responsible for the dropdown.

Answer (score 1):

Change your nav bar tag as bellow:

```
<nav class="top-bar" data-options="back_text: custom_text">
```